# Invalid Command 'RedirectMatch' - Apache 2.47. Ubuntu Trust

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I've got a .htaccess file, as below, and i'm getting the error 
`Invalid command 'RedirectMatch', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. I've done a lot of searching and can't find what the problem is, mod rewrite is loaded and seemingly working otherwise.

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any help or guidance would be great.

```
# rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# enable awesome urls. i.e.:
# http://yourdomain.com/about-us/team
RewriteEngine on

# make sure to set the RewriteBase correctly
# if you are running the site in a subfolder.
# Otherwise links or the entire site will break.
#
# If your homepage is http://yourdomain.com/mysite
# Set the RewriteBase to:
#
# RewriteBase /mysite
#
RewriteBase /

# force www on domain
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# block text files in the content folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# block all files in the kirby folder from being accessed directly
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) error [R=301,L]

# leave robots.txt alone for search engines
RewriteRule ^robots.txt robots.txt [L]

# redirect /cashback to home
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cashback/?$ http://www.example.com/

# add trailing slash to links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mod rewrite is loaded and seemingly working otherwise.
>   `RedirectMatch 301 ^/cashback/?$ http://www.example.com/`

`RedirectMatch` is part of mod_alias, not mod_rewrite. Although mod_alias is usually loaded by default unless it has been specifically removed?

However, you should not mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite redirects. Since they belong to different modules they execute at different times (mod_rewrite generally first) so you can get unexpected conflicts. Since you are already using mod_rewrite for everything else, you should rework this redirect using mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) instead. Like so:

```
RewriteRule ^cashback/?$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's someone else's code so didn't even check that it was correct! Solved it perfectly!